# Azure speech to text Cognitive services - Audio stream input

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions, blazor-webassembly, azure-signalr

Trying to create a code in blazor application for continuous speech to text using azure cognitive services. I am trying to use Stream of input instead of voice from Microphone. Any suggestion would be helpful.

```
  var audioFormat = AudioStreamFormat.GetWaveFormatPCM(16000, 16, 1);
            var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(audioStream, audioFormat);
```

This audio stream how to pass it from client to server?

Comment: can you please share your program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the given below Microsoft documentation link, **Audio can be streamed into the recognizer using the Speech SDK**.

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-audio-input-streams***

Firstly, `recognize the audio input stream format which must be supported in Azure cognitive services. Then, verify that your code meets with these requirements by providing the RAW audio`. Once done, then **Adapt PullAudioInputStreamCallback to create your own audio input stream class**. Depending on your audio format and input stream, **create an audio configuration**. `When you construct your recognizer, provide both the audio input setup and your normal speech configuration to the recognizer`.

**Example code: -**

```
#
var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(new 
ContosoAudioStream(config), audioFormat);
var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(...);
var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();// Run stream through recognizer.
var text = result.GetText();
```

Comment: Thanks for the update.Could you please let me know how to pass audio input stream from client in UI using razor pages and also using signalR hubconnection